# Is there a metrizable topology on tempered distributions for which sequential convergence is pointwise?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Is there a metrizable topology on $S’$ (the set of linear continuous functionals in Schwarz’s space) whose convergent sequences are the sequences that converge pointwise?

The obvious topology with these convergent sequences is the weak* topology, which I know is not metrizable.  However, there might be another topology with the same convergent sequences which is metrizable.

I know that for smooth functions, there is no such metrizable topology whose convergent sequences are the pointwise convergent sequences.

But I don’t know how prove this. Maybe it is classical fact, but I didn’t find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "pointwise convergence", precisely?  I would think that is a synonym for the weak* topology.

Comment: Yes, pointwise convergence = convergence in *-weak topology. 
$F_n\rightarrow F$ if and only if $\forall \phi \in S \hspace{0.5em} F_n(\phi)\rightarrow F(\phi)$

Comment: So what is your question then?  You said you already know why the weak* topology is not metrizable.

Comment: No, I mean that on $S’$ can be two different topologies. And sets of converging sequences in these topologies may be equal. As for arbitrary topological space.

Comment: Ah, it makes a big difference that you are talking about pointwise convergence of only *sequences* (and this was not clear in your original question!).  If you were talking about pointwise convergence of nets then that would uniquely determine the weak* topology.